# React/Styled-Components buttons hover trigger Legend fade in. Can't work out how to fade OUT

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, styled-components

I've build a sample component of what I'm using [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/legend-fades-lln3ts?file=/src/Hobbies.jsx).
I have a series of icons, and when the cursor hovers them, the legend for each of them is displayed in another element. This works fine.
I wanted to fade IN the legend (TextContainerBox), it works also.
But I can't work out how to give the fadeOutDown effect (keyframes in sandbox) to the TextContainerBox before I set the state to close and it disapears. For now, I've been testing on the first icon, so my code attempts differ on the others.

The difficulty is that one element triggers another.

(the fadeoutdown effect is on hover on the Bloop element (the teal square) at the bottom and is functional)

I'm a newbie and I've gotten this far on my own, but now my brain is getting stuck on the logic here. I hope someone can help! :)